# PHP json_encode encoding accents in words

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, opencart

I'm using Opencart, and althought I have seen basically every post on google about this subject, I can't figure out why the database is saving letters with accents in a non utf8 encoding.

```
print_r($this->request->post);
```

Returns: `Array ( [pfa_status] => 1 [pfa_text] => 'Cobrança' );`
But after aplying the `json_encode` it becomes:

```
{"pfa_status":"1","pfa_text":"Cobran\u00e7a"}
```

Now by looking at all the possible solutions through web:

1. I use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">`
2. I have tried `header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');`
3. All my files have the format `utf-8 without BOM`
4. I use `$this->connection->set_charset("utf8");`
5. I use `$this->connection->query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");`
6. My field in the database, where is saved the json, has the collation `utf8_bin`
7. When using `json_decode` it remains with wrong encoding
8. Tried `json_encode($this->request->post, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

So, whenever I show the value of `pfa_text` after being decoded, it shows `Cobran\u00e7a` instead of `Cobrança`.

What am I missing?

---

**EDIT 1**: As requested, here's my code just for the sake of testing.

```
class ControllerPfa extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')) 
        {
            $value = json_encode($this->request->post, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            print_r($value);

            die();
        }
    }
}
```

So the output is (and take notice that it is the full current $_POST response):

```
{"pfa_status":"1","pfa_sort_order":"","pfa":[{"payment_method":"cod","description":{"1":{"name":"Tax"},"3":{"name":"Cobran\u00e7a"},"4":{"name":"Cobran\u00e7a"}}}]}
```

---

**EDIT 2**: I'm using the version 7.0 of PHP

[image]

---

**EDIT 3**: Solved, the following function allows the words to be perfectly inserted in the database with accents.

```
private function formatEncoding($value)
{
    return preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u(\w{4})/', function ($matc) 
    {
        return html_entity_decode('&#x' . $matc[1] . ';', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    }, $value);
}
```

So, all we have to do is call `formatEncoding(json_encode($this->request->post));`

Comment: Deceze, it's not duplicated if the answers told in that post didn't work for me, don't you think?

Comment: FWIW, this is not reproducible in any recent PHP version: https://3v4l.org/6I1l4. Either something about the input is not as you think, or you're somehow unexpectedly running on an ancient PHP version.

Comment: What about look at my post? I even post a print of my current PHP version.

Comment: Yes, after your edits it's not exactly a duplicate. However, again, it's not reproducible with any stock PHP 7 install. Can you produce a **simple** minimal sample code which shows this behaviour on any default PHP 7?

Comment: I wouldn't be the first time someone thinks they're running some specific PHP version when actually it turns out there's some other web server running on their system and really their code is executing on ancient PHP. To rule that out, and to rule out Opencart is doing any shenanigans, provide a sample anyone can run anywhere that proves a specific PHP version is producing a specific unexpected result.

Comment: I solved with the solution someone post here but then deleted. Since I can no longer answer to my post, I'll edit.

Comment: `echo $this->request->post;` -- I suspect it already has `\u...`

Answer (score 3):

One of the options you can pass in the [second parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) of `json_encode` is `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`. This is described as:

> Encode multibyte Unicode characters literally (default is to escape as \uXXXX). Available since PHP 5.4.0.

So if you pass that, it should work because it prevents them from being escaped:

```
$json = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Doesn't work either. I have tried that.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Version 7, see my edited post please.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the flag **JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE** (see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php))

like this:

```
echo json_encode(
     $data ,
     JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
);
```

Comment: Forget to tell I have tried that without success.

Comment: yeah, that would've been valuable information. so could you possibly provide a minimal example of your code for further debugging?

Comment: Look at my edited post.